Disabling some symbols from being prettified in a given mode
In AucTeX, I want to use prettify-symbols-mode but not prettify "--" and "---".
Why is the following not working?
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
                               (setq prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point 'right-edge)
                               (setq tex--prettify-symbols-alist
                                     (assq-delete-all "---"
                                                      (assq-delete-all "--" tex--prettify-symbols-alist)))
                               (prettify-symbols-mode)))


Distinct string objects are never eq (even if their values are equal, they are not the same object).  Hence you are not removing anything from that list with assq-delete-all.  You should be using assoc-delete-all.
You also only need to modify the value of tex--prettify-symbols-alist once (as it's global), so I suggest you instead do this:
(with-eval-after-load "tex-mode"
  ;; Do not prettify "---" or "--" in LaTeX buffers.
  (setq tex--prettify-symbols-alist
        (assoc-delete-all
         "---" (assoc-delete-all
                "--" tex--prettify-symbols-alist))))

(defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  "Called in `LaTeX-mode-hook'."
  (setq-local prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point 'right-edge)
  (prettify-symbols-mode 1))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-LaTeX-mode-hook)

Note that prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point is not automatically buffer-local, so I've made that a setq-local.  (Or if you want that globally then just set the global value once, outside of any mode hooks.)

... or the alist could be set locally in the hook as well, right?

Sort of.  It would work somewhat by chance(1), and it's not what I'd suggest.  Setting the buffer-local prettify-symbols-alist in a mode hook is common enough OTOH; but tex--prettify-symbols-alist only needs to be modified once, so setting it repeatedly is redundant.

(1) If "--" and "---" were the first items in the alist then it wouldn't work the first time, because prettify-symbols-alist would already have been set to the original cons cell before the hook ran.

(See tex-common-initialization which is called in the body of tex-mode.)

I see - thanks!
